# Empty XML text node returned from jQuery .ajax in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to extract a string from an ajax query XML result.
This works perfectly in IE9, but in IE8 the text node containing the string is empty.
I have tried changing the dataType to text and seen that this is the case.
I have also verified that the mime-type being returned is text/xml.

Here is the text of my function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myURL,
    cache: false,
    data: myData,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "XML",
    success: function(xmlData) {
        Result=$(xmlData).find("Output").text();
    }
});
```

Here is the structure of the responseXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Rowsets ... >
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column ... />
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <Output>
                *string to be extracted*
            </Output>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

In IE8 the  node is empty.  In IE9 it contains the string data.  My application requires that I support both browsers.  How can I retrieve my data in both IE8 and IE9?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was in myData, the data being supplied to the server.  As it consisted of HTML code, IE8 and IE9 formatted it differently, resulting in processing errors.

Thank you to anybody who read this.